# Can low or dead CMOS battery cause booting issues?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Let me get straight to my problem. Today morning when I opened my laptop, I got a window saying "**Time-of-day not set - please run SETUP program**" with 3 options

-> Continue
-> BIOS-Setup
-> Diagnostics

I pressed continue and booted into Windows 11 where I got the Blue screen of death saying YOUR PC RAN INTO A PROBLEM. error code : `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.
Since I run dual boot with Windows alongside Linux, I booted into Linux and it also displayed something similar saying

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/920903aa-762f-40d2-8126-87f4b0e6f975 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.10.3-7ubuntu1.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

Then I did a hardware scan from dell BIOS and after that now laptop won't even show the GRUB menu and it says no bootable devices found with a large beep.

I have read that CMOS can cause this issue. I also did a disk scan using dell supportAssist and no issues were detected.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I think this should be transferred to SU

Comment: Hi Arjun, try posting on Superuser